# Python Right-To-Left support GUI framework

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform

I have to write a cross-platform desktop application in persian language using python-2.7.

So, can anybody suggest me a cross-platform GUI toolkit for python that supports RTL and Bidirectional text writing and rendering ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Qt framework](http://qt-project.org/) has good right-to-left support. Have you consider looking at Python bindings for it like [PySide](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide) or [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)?